# Why did Dr Azad pay for Chanu's ticket to Bangladesh?

Tags: character-analysis, monica-ali, brick-lane

> "Dr. Azad," she said. "Why did you give my husband that money?"
>
> The end of his nose was pitted with age, his cheeks had given way to jowls, pockets of air puffed the skin around his eyes, when he smiled the corners of his mouth turned down, and it was a big, generous smile.
>
> "It's very simple. Because he is my friend. My very good friend."

In the book *Brick Lane*, Chanu and Dr Azad have a somewhat strange relationship. The upshot seems to be that they like to needle each other, so keep seeing each other.

So why does Dr Azad give him all that money to go back to Bangladesh? We see their relationship from Nazneen's perspective. Is it possible she didn't understand it, or misrepresented it?